# Cleaning data - Remove repeating sequences of 23 zeros and number from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sequence, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe time series of wind speed data from large number of weather stations. Several stations contains repeating sequences of 23 zeros and a number e.g

```
Station_code    4726631C    4726A602    4726C3E4
Datetime            
2015-03-01 00:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 01:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 02:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 03:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 04:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 05:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 06:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 07:00:00     NaN     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 08:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 09:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 10:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 11:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 12:00:00     2.4     2.7     1.9<<
2015-03-01 13:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 14:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 15:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 16:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 17:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 18:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 19:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 20:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 21:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 22:00:00     NaN     0.0     0.0
2015-03-01 23:00:00     0.0     0.0     NaN
2015-03-02 00:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 01:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 02:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 03:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 04:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 05:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 06:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 07:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 08:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 09:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 10:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 11:00:00     0.0     0.0     0.0
2015-03-02 12:00:00     2.4     2.7     1.9<<
```

To make things a bit more spicy, some of the zeros are NaNs, but usefully the number appears at hour = 12:00
The repeating nature indicates it is erroneous data so needs to be removed.

I was thinking something like:

```
if data at df.index.hour = 12 is preceded by 23 values where np.nanmean = 0 then make all values in sequence = np.nan
```

But I am new to python and not sure how to translate this into a script.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: There is real data (with real zeros) later on but the data is interspersed with these sequences (23 x zeros, 1 x number) so I want to remove the entire sequence (I think)

Comment: Thanks - if i understand the code snip, it fills all NaN with 0, but there are "real" NaNs in there too, which I need to keep (the data is five years so hard to post the entire set!)

Comment: Yes, there are ~150 stations although not all appear to contain this sequence

Comment: then the criteria for dropping columns isn't met, there is no count of 23 rows of 0 values across all three columns.

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm not being clear. I'm not trying to drop columns, just delete those repeating sequences